# Running unknown apps securely

Tags: security, application, access-control

What would be the fastest way to run unknown scripts and apps in *nix environments?

For example, to forbid writing and reading outside the working directory. Or to restrict access to hardware and most commands.

A virtual machine seems to be the most flexible. Adding a new restricted user is another option.

Are there better ways?

Answer (score 2):

You can use namespaces to isolate the unknown process from the rest of the system; one tool which simplifies this, with a specific emphasis on security, is [bubblewrap](https://github.com/projectatomic/bubblewrap) (which is used *e.g.* by [Flatpak](http://www.flatpak.org/)).

On Fedora-style systems, it’s as simple as

```
bwrap --ro-bind /usr /usr --symlink usr/lib64 /lib64 --proc /proc --dev /dev --unshare-pid bash
```

but you should read the documentation.

This approach is more secure than using restricted users, and lighter weight than using a VM. Whether that’s better depends on your exact requirements.

Comment: Firejail  (https://github.com/netblue30/firejail) is another good option.

Comment: @Austin indeed; but it’s worth pondering [the comparison](https://github.com/projectatomic/bubblewrap#related-project-comparison-firejail) in bubblewrap’s documentation.